# doing a program using Roman numerals and making them int

Tags: c++, loops, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My output is outputting correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949071/my-output-is-outputting-correctly)

this is a homework problem.  I know some of the Roman numerals are not correct.  My teacher doesn't care how to write the number correctly as long as the value is correct.

I have a few issues with this program.  I don't know any other way to get out of the while loop except asking for the user to press "E".

Once I do this the output changes to say  `cout << "The first number is " << RomanNum1 << endl;` is E instead of V or VI or whatever.

I am supposed to use functions and I am not worried about making those.  The bottom part of the program is what my teacher wants the output to look like.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
//This programs reads in Roman numerals and outputs the correct numerical value. 
//This program will do simple math using Roman numerals and output a numerical value
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char One = 'I';
const char Five = 'V';
const char Ten = 'X';
const char Fifty = 'L';
const char OneHundred = 'C';
const char FiveHundred = 'D';
const char OneThousand = 'M';
const char EXIT = 'E';
const char Plus = '+';
const char Minus = '-';
const char Times = '*';
const char Divide = '/';

const int ValueOfOne = 1;
const int ValueOfFive = 5;
const int ValueOfTen = 10;
const int ValueOfFifty = 50;
const int ValueOfOneHundred = 100;
const int ValueOfFiveHundred = 500;
const int ValueOfOneThousand = 1000;

int main (){
    char RomanNum1, RomanNum2;
    char Operation;
    int Answer; 
    string Response;

    int ICount = 0;
    int VCount = 0;
    int XCount = 0;
    int LCount = 0;
    int CCount = 0;
    int DCount = 0;
    int MCount = 0;

    int Sum = 0;


    cin >> RomanNum1;
    while (RomanNum1 != EXIT){

        if (RomanNum1 == One){
            ICount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum1 == Five){
            VCount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum1 == Ten){
            XCount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum1 == Fifty){
            LCount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum1 == OneHundred){
            CCount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum1 == FiveHundred){
            DCount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum1 == OneThousand){
            MCount++;
        }
        else {
            RomanNum1 = EXIT;
        }
        cin >> RomanNum1;
    }

    cin >> RomanNum2;
    while (RomanNum2 != EXIT){

        if (RomanNum2 == One){
            ICount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum2 == Five){
            VCount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum2 == Ten){
            XCount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum2 == Fifty){
            LCount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum2 == OneHundred){
            CCount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum2 == FiveHundred){
            DCount++;
        }
        else if (RomanNum2 == OneThousand){
            MCount++;
        }
        else {
            RomanNum2 = EXIT;
        }
        cin >> RomanNum2;
    }

    cin >> Operation;
    if (Operation == Plus){
        Answer = RomanNum1 + RomanNum2;
        Response = "sum";
    }
    else if (Operation == Minus){
        Answer = RomanNum1 - RomanNum2;
        Response = "difference";
    }
    else if (Operation == Times){
        Answer = RomanNum1 * RomanNum2;
        Response = "product";
    }
    else {
        Answer = RomanNum1 / RomanNum2;
        Response = "quotient";
    }

    Sum = ValueOfOne * ICount + ValueOfFive * VCount + ValueOfTen * XCount 
        + ValueOfFifty * LCount + ValueOfOneHundred * CCount + ValueOfFiveHundred 
        * DCount + ValueOfOneThousand * MCount;

    cout << "The first number is " << RomanNum1 << endl;
    cout << "The second number is " << RomanNum2 << endl;
    cout << "Arithmetic operation is " << Operation << endl;
    cout << "The " << Response << " of " << RomanNum1 << " and " << RomanNum2 << " is " << Sum << endl;

    return 0;
}

/* here is what the output should be
Input for Run 1:
MCCXXVI
LXVIIII
+
DCX
MCI
-
LXVI
CCLXI
/
MD
XXX
/
LXVIIII
XXVIIII
*

The output for Test Run 1: 
MCCXXVI
The first number is 1226
LXVIIII
The second number is 69
+
Arithmetic operation is +
The sum of 1226 and 69 is MCCLXXXXV (1295)

DCX
The first number is 610
MCI
The second number is 1101
-
Arithmetic operation is -
The difference of 610 and 1101 is -CCCCLXXXXI (-491)*/
```

Comment: As a side note, if you have learned how arrays work yet, I highly recommend creating either a parallel or multidimensional array that links the roman numeral to its integer counterpart. Doing so would make management of code easier and keep your code tidier.

Comment: Well, yes, the Roman numerals aren't handled correctly, but what is the question exactly? Anyway, I can upvote because your code doesn't generate any warnings, even with `-Wall -Wextra`. One doesn't see that often.

Comment: we can't use arrays in this program

Comment: Write a C++ program to implement a form of a Roman numeral calculator.
We are using the purely additive form of Roman numerals.  By that, we
mean that a number is simply the sum of its digits; for example, 4 equals
IIII, in our additive notation.  This means that we are NOT using IV for 4.
Each Roman numeral must start with the digit of highest value and ends with
the digit of smallest value.  That is 9 is VIIII and NOT IIIIV.
Your program continually (in a loop) inputs 2 Roman numbers and an
arithmetic operator and prints the result of the operation as a Roman
number.

Answer (score 2):

Hi one hint about roman numerals. When smaller values precede larger values, the smaller values are subtracted from the larger values, and the result is added to the total. For example IV = 4.
For more details check the related wikipedia page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals

So the summing part should be revised.

And in general, whenever you see some repetition in your code, do not hesitate to extract it to a method.

And if the homework has to be in c++ it is high time to create a RomanNumeral class :)

Comment: Oh, yes. A RomanNumeral class with overloaded >> and << operators, integer storage internally, and then overload +,-,*,/...homework done!

Comment: Im not allowed to use array sin this program.  If we do we lose all points.  Also he doesn't care about the order.  If the number is VIX it should print out XVI = 16.